# Can one stage belong to different jobs in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Following is a piece code of the spark's Stage class, it defines a `jobIds`, which is a `HashSet`, so it means that one stage can belong to different jobs. I have always thought that one stage can only belong to only  one job, could someone show some example code that demonstrate this?

```
private[scheduler] abstract class Stage(
    val id: Int,
    val rdd: RDD[_],
    val numTasks: Int,
    val parents: List[Stage],
    val firstJobId: Int,
    val callSite: CallSite)
  extends Logging {

  val numPartitions = rdd.partitions.length

  /** Set of jobs that this stage belongs to. */
  val jobIds = new HashSet[Int]

  /** The ID to use for the next new attempt for this stage. */
  private var nextAttemptId: Int = 0

  val name: String = callSite.shortForm
  val details: String = callSite.longForm
}
```

Comment: A stage is reattempted in case of failure